# Set From name to running user while sending email using Organization - Wide address

Tags: email, case, service-cloud-console, email2case

We use cases internally, and are looking to personalize our outbound case responses to display the `From Name` of the live human who is actually responding to the ticket.

We must use our email-to-case address as the from address, so that responses are routed back to the case.

Success would be if instead of emails coming from Salesforce Support (support@abc.com), the email would come from Gorav Seth (support@abc.com).

The only option I can envision would be to create copies of our `organization-wide address` for every person in my team, with the from name set appropriately - which isnt really an option, if it would work at all.

Is there any other way to accomplish this (lightning, service cloud, case feed, watson)?

We are currently in classic, without case feed, but willing to move out of the stone age for the right reward.

Answer (score 0):

Can you uncheck the below option in support settings?

**Support Settings - Send Case Notifications from System Address**